# Check if comma separated values in a dataframe contains values from another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, partial

I have 2 dataframes

df1 has a list of users and assets

```
    print(df1)  
        User       Asset
    0   user_1   asset_1,asset_2,asset_3 
    1   user_2    asset_4  
    2   user_3    asset_5
```

df2 gives a list of expired assets

```
    print(df2)  
        Asset
    0   asset_2 
    1   asset_5  
    2   asset_6
```

I want to flag any expired assets in df1 as below

```
    print(df1)  
        User       Asset                    Flag
    0   user_1   asset_1,asset_2,asset_3   Expired
    1   user_2    asset_4                     
    2   user_3    asset_5                  Expired
```

I am using the below piece of code which i know is incorrect and need help with the right syntax which will help me compare comma separated values to values in another df

```
df1.loc[df1['Asset'].isin(df2['Asset']), 'Flag'] = 'Expired'
```

thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `split` and `explode` the list of assets, merge it to `df2` and set `Flag` when there's a match:

```
In [129]: df1['Flag'] = ''

In [130]: df1.loc[df1['Asset'].str.split(',').explode().reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].unique(), 'Flag'] = 'Expired'

In [131]: df1
Out[131]:
     User                    Asset     Flag
0  user_1  asset_1,asset_2,asset_3  Expired
1  user_2                  asset_4
2  user_3                  asset_5  Expired
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with `split` then `any` and apply the condition to `np.where`

```
df1['Flag']=np.where(df1.Asset.str.split(',',expand=True).isin(df2.Asset.tolist()).any(1), 'expired','')
df1
Out[46]: 
     User                    Asset     Flag
0  user_1  asset_1,asset_2,asset_3  expired
1  user_2                  asset_4         
2  user_3                  asset_5  expired
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a mask using [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here.

```
mask = df1['Asset'].str.contains('|'.join([r'\b'+i+r'\b' for i in df2['Asset']]))
df1['Flag'] = np.where(mask, 'expired', '')

     User                    Asset     Flag
0  user_1  asset_1,asset_2,asset_3  expired
1  user_2                  asset_4
2  user_3                  asset_5  expired
```

If you want `NaN` instead of `''`(empty string) you use `df.loc` here.

```
df1.loc[mask, 'nflag'] = 'expired'
     User                    Asset     Flag    nflag
0  user_1  asset_1,asset_2,asset_3  expired  expired
1  user_2                  asset_4               NaN #---> `NaN` instead of `''`
2  user_3                  asset_5  expired  expired
```

Details about [`regex pattern` here](https://regex101.com/r/6e4H2R/2)