# Pandas dataframe: Flag a row when column value is in comma-separated string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

```
df   Item    ItemList   
1      a       r,t,y     
2      b       z,q,b     
3      c         c,d     
4      b           a     
5      a         a,z
```

and I want to check for each row if item is in itemList, and if so add a Flag like this :

```
df   Item    ItemList   Flag
1      a       r,t,y     NaN
2      b       z,q,b     Yes
3      c         c,d     Yes
4      b           a     NaN
5      a         a,z     Yes
```

The only answer I found so far is this one:

[Check if comma separated values in a dataframe contains values from another dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145697/check-if-comma-separated-values-in-a-dataframe-contains-values-from-another-data)

But using isin() does not seem to do the trick row by row.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if exist values by splitted `ItemList` in list comprehension with `zip` and `if-else` use for set `Yes` or missing values:

```
df['Flag'] = ['Yes' if x in y.split(',') 
                     else np.nan for x, y in zip(df['Item'], df['ItemList'])]

print (df)
   df Item ItemList Flag
0   1    a    r,t,y  NaN
1   2    b    z,q,b  Yes
2   3    c      c,d  Yes
3   4    b        a  NaN
4   5    a      a,z  Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Item":["a","b","c","b","a"],"ItemList":["r,t,y","z,q,b","c,d","a","a,z"]})
df["Flag"] = df.apply(lambda row:"Yes" if row.Item in row.ItemList.split(",") else "NaN",axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
  Item ItemList Flag
0    a    r,t,y  NaN
1    b    z,q,b  Yes
2    c      c,d  Yes
3    b        a  NaN
4    a      a,z  Yes
```

Explanation: `.apply` with `axis=1` apply function to each row, function (here `lambda`) accept row as `pandas.Series`

Answer (score 0):

If you have many repeated items in `Item` (ie. few groups), it might be advantageous to use `groupby`:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df.groupby('Item')['ItemList']
                        .apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(s.name)),
                      'Yes', np.nan)
```

output:

```
  Item ItemList Flag
0    a    r,t,y  NaN
1    b    z,q,b  Yes
2    c      c,d  Yes
3    b        a  NaN
4    a      a,z  Yes
```